# Exception with Transaction Reaper

Tags: spring, spring-boot, amqp, spring-transactions, rabbitmqctl

We have a spring boot app running in Prod and this wierd exception below repeated in the logs, do anyone has idea? why it happens?

2024-01-11 14:14:48,759 WARN ? [Transaction Reaper] ARJUNA012117: TransactionReaper::check processing TX 0:ffffc0******:-481e****:658a****:d4*** in state  SCHEDULE_CANCEL

i try to search for the causing but nothing works